# Graphql - creating a schema from a generated JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I'm trying to create a custom graphql schema to use on my graphql yoga server. The graphql yoga server is just a proxy to another graphql API from which I have managed to retrieve a schema from in `JSON` format. Here is a preview of what that schema looks like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "__schema": {
      "queryType": {
        "name": "Query"
      },
      "mutationType": null,
      "subscriptionType": null,
      "types": [
        {
          "kind": "OBJECT",
          "name": "Core",
          "description": null,
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "_meta",
              "description": null,
              "args": [],
              "type": {
                "kind": "NON_NULL",
                "name": null,
                "ofType": {
                  "kind": "OBJECT",
                  "name": "Meta",
                  "ofType": null
                }
              },
              "isDeprecated": false,
              "deprecationReason": null
            },
            {
              "name": "_linkType",
              "description": null,
              "args": [],
              "type": {
                "kind": "SCALAR",
                "name": "String",
                "ofType": null
              },
              "isDeprecated": false,
              "deprecationReason": null
            }
          ],
          "inputFields": null,
          "interfaces": [
            {
```

I now want to take this generated JSON schema and use it to create a graphql schema to use in my graphql yoga server. I believe the correct way to do this is by using the `new GraphQLSchema` method from graphql along with a root query. Here is my code attempting this:

```
schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: schema.data.__schema
  })
});
```

The above code gives me the following error:

> Error: Query.mutationType field config must be an object

Not entirely sure where it's going wrong or if this is the proper approach to creating a graphql schema from generated JSON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JSON you have is the results of an [introspection query](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Introspection). Unfortunately, introspection will not allow you to copy a remote schema. That's because while it does identify what fields exist in a schema, it does not tell you anything about how they should be executed. For example, based on the snippet you posted, we know the remote server exposes a `_meta` query that returns a `Meta` type -- but we don't know what code to run to resolve the value returned by the query.

Technically, it's possible to pass the results of an introspection query to `buildClientSchema` from the `graphql/utilities` module. However, the schema will not be executable, as the docs point out:

> Given the result of a client running the introspection query, creates and returns a GraphQLSchema instance which can be then used with all GraphQL.js tools, but cannot be used to execute a query, as introspection does not represent the "resolver", "parse" or "serialize" functions or any other server-internal mechanisms.

If you want to create a proxy to another GraphQL endpoint, the easiest way is to use `makeRemoteExecutableSchema` from `graphql-tools`.

Here's the example based on [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/remote-schemas.html#makeRemoteExecutableSchema):

```
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const link = new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://your-endpoint-url/graphql', fetch });
async function getRemoteSchema () {
  const schema = await introspectSchema(link);
  return makeRemoteExecutableSchema({
    schema,
    link,
  });
}
```

The resulting schema is a `GraphQLSchema` object that can be used like normal:

```
import { GraphQLServer } from 'graphql-yoga'

async function startServer () {
  const schema = await introspectSchema(link);
  const executableSchema = makeRemoteExecutableSchema({
    schema,
    link,
  });
  const server = new GraphQLServer({ schema: executableSchema })
  server.start()
}

startServer()
```

`graphql-tools` also allows you to [stitch schemas together](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-stitching.html) if you not only wanted to proxy the existing endpoint, but wanted to add on to it as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So presumably I should be able to just insert the schema into the graphql yoga config like so : `const server = new GraphQLServer({ 
  schema: getRemoteSchema(),
  context: req => ({ ...req, Prismic })
})`. If so it's generating an error saying "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Comment: I should also note that getRemoteSchema is returning me something thats not an error

Comment: In the example, `getRemoteSchema` returns a Promise, so you can't just pass it directly to `GraphQLServer`'s constructor. I've updated the answer with a more complete example using `graphql-yoga`. If you're seeing a malformed JSON error, though, that probably means your call to the external server is failing. Check your endpoint URL.

Comment: Works perfectly now, thanks for the detailed explanation!